# ajax post request with multiple paramaters

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UserRoleChanged(string roleName,string userName)
{
     var a = roleName;
     var b = userName;
     return RedirectToAction("UserManager");
}
```

Script in view:

```
if (window.confirm('Are you sure that you want to change role?')) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("UserRoleChanged", "DashBoard")",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { 'roleName': this.text, 'userName': 'SomeName'},
                cache: false,
                success: function (data){
                window.location.href = data;
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                }
        })};
```

When I run script above UserRoleChanged action does not invoke. If I try to remove userName variable from data in ajax then UserRoleChanged  action method invokes without any problem. How can i pass multiple data to my controller? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Remove the `dataType: 'json'` from the ajax, and try again

Comment: Why using AJAX call to perform `RedirectToAction`? Using form submit is more preferred there.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz thank you so much. It worked perfectly..

Comment: Its an ajax call - they never redirect (the whole point of them is to stay on the **same** page)

Comment: Just make a normal submit - all your doing is degrading performance

Comment: Thank you. I wont redirect anywhere from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `dataType: 'json'` from the ajax, and try again. As you are trying to get the values on server side as normal variable, so `dataType: 'json'` is not required here.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model with same properties and pass it as a parameter. Its a good practice.

Looks like this.

```
public class User
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

And the json looks like this example

```
{
    "RoleName" : "somename",
    "UserName" : "somename"
}
```